# WMS layers rendering slow in Open layers 3?

Tags: azure, openlayers-3, geoserver, postgresql-9.5

I have Geoserver 2.11.2,PostgreSQL 9.5,open layers 3 and Tomcat 8 all are installed on Ubuntu 16.4 Azure cloud virtual machine.I also enabled GeoWebCache but still WMS layer rendering speed is slow(15 to 16 seconds).Please find [this](http://uxo.azurewebsites.net/webmap/Index.html) .Is there any idea to improve more speed than the current speed of web-tool,Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Broadly, it sounds like something is misconfigured.  There are some excellent resources in the GeoServer docs (http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/production/) about running in production.  From GeoSolutions, there is some training materials (http://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/enterprise/index.html) and talks (https://www.slideshare.net/geosolutions/geoserver-in-production-we-do-it-here-is-how-foss4g-2016) which address common techniques for data prep, JVM options, and other considerations which may help some.

As a particular call-out, I'd strongly suggest Marlin (https://github.com/bourgesl/marlin-renderer/wiki/How-to-use).  Its use in GeoServer can help immensely with concurrent rendering (http://www.geo-solutions.it/blog/developerss-corner-achieving-extreme-geoserver-scalability-with-the-new-marlin-vector-rasterizer/).

It may be worth making sure that PostGIS is installed and that your data has a spatial index.  Tuning PostGIS is a separate topic.

Once the data is prepped and indexed and Marlin is up and running, it may be worth seeding the GWC cache.  With that, your application would just be serving pre-baked tiles for coarse zoom levels and that should be snappier.

Comment: Thanks GeoMesaJim,I increased Geoserver JAI memory and  also Enabled  direct integration with Geoserver WMS. data has spatial index as well and followed your suggestions but still i am unable to increase web map loading speed.

Comment: I have Open JDK 1.8,so can i change Open JDK to Oracle JDK.Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at the GWC UI to see how the cache is working?  Perhaps it isn't being used efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a **lot** of layers turned on in your map. Just zooming in once triggered a total of **700** individual tile requests, most of them to your GeoServer. I don't think your main problem is your GeoServer (although tweaking it using the other answers suggestions is always a good idea), I think your main problem is simply throughput.

Most browsers have a limit (when using http 1.1) of [how many simultaneous requests can be sent to the same domain](http://www.browserscope.org/?category=network), once you hit that limit, all other requests are queued until the previous ones are done. I think that's your problem, your server is dealing with the requests as quickly as it can, but there are so many that it simply cannot serve them at the speed you are expecting.

I would strongly recommend you look at reducing the number of layers you have loaded by default, or implement some kind of zoom restriction so that certain layers turn off at different zoom levels. You could even think about combining a number of the layers into one and perhaps using [GeoServers CQL filtering](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/cql/cql_tutorial.html) to change what is displayed.

Comment: Thanks Rob,Is there any problem because of bootstrap library.I tested online,so result shows,more time taking for java script code.

Comment: Ah! Perhaps you could change OpenLayers or Leaflet to make non-tiled requests.